# Bootstrap Carousel refuses to work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel, bootstrap-4

i have tried everything, including this code which is straight from ww3 itself, with added cdn. 
it worked on bootstrap 4 beta but everything else on my site works on an earlier version and im new and superstitious about run time; don't wish to include them both if i dont have to

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
    <body>



         <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="myCarousel">

            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
              <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
              <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
              <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>

            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
              <div class="item active">
                <img src="https://media.galaxant.com/000/462/866/desktop-1462221325.png" alt="spacious tent">
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/98/4f/f8/984ff8bea911ffb5977635185d79396e.jpg" alt="lots of head room">
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <img src="http://kitchenfunwithmy3sons.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/the-best-camping-ideas-hacks-gear-tips-and-tricks-37.jpg" alt="no bull crap">
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--End listbox-->

            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            </a>

            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </a>


            <script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
          </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Could you explain WHAT does not work?

Comment: the slides, it looks exactly like it should. you can't change by clicking buttons (the little circles or the carousel-control) and it won't cicle

Comment: apart from the arrows jumping between pics the slider works fine.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/qolanonoyo/1/edit?html,output — I can't reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your **JQuery** version has some issues. Try using some older version. For demo purpose, I replaced it with `vers.2.1` and it's working. 
And you do not need to repeat your **CSS linking**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<body>



  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="myCarousel">

    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://media.galaxant.com/000/462/866/desktop-1462221325.png" alt="spacious tent">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/98/4f/f8/984ff8bea911ffb5977635185d79396e.jpg" alt="lots of head room">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://kitchenfunwithmy3sons.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/the-best-camping-ideas-hacks-gear-tips-and-tricks-37.jpg" alt="no bull crap">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--End listbox-->

    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>

    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>


    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  </div>
```